# My simple c++ text game doesn't work. i'm using random number generates and i'm confused

Tags: c++, visual-studio, if-statement, while-loop, visual-studio-2015

So basically when I compile and run, it will work all the way up until I "Begin combat!!" but I don't understand what is wrong with my loop. This code should work perfectly fine to my eyes, but I need some help figuring out why I have bad vision.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <ctime>
#include <random>

using namespace std;

int main() {
    mt19937 randGen(time(NULL));
    uniform_int_distribution<int> humanatt(4, 8);
    uniform_int_distribution<int> humanhp(50, 100);
    uniform_int_distribution<int> skelatt(12, 17);
    uniform_int_distribution<int> skelhp(70, 85);
    int hAtt, hHp, sAtt, sHp;
    unsigned long humans, skeletons, deadHumans = 0, deadSkeletons = 0;
    cout << "*** Skeletons vs Humans ***" << endl;
    cout << "Input the number of humans: ";
    cin >> humans;
    cout << "Input the number of skeletons: ";
    cin >> skeletons;
    cout << "Beginning combat!!" << endl << endl << "(combat noises)" << endl;

    while ((humans > 0) && (skeletons > 0)) {
        hAtt = humanatt(randGen);
        hHp = humanhp(randGen);
        sAtt = skelatt(randGen);
        sHp = skelhp(randGen);

        while ((hHp > 0) && (sHp > 0)) {
            if (hAtt >= sHp) {
                skeletons--;
                deadHumans++;
            }
            if (sAtt >= hHp) {
                humans--;
                deadHumans++;
            }
        }

    }
    cout << endl << "Combat has ended!" << endl << endl;
    if ((humans == 0) && (skeletons == 0)) {
        cout << "They all died!" << endl;
        cout << "This was a battle with no winner" << endl;
        cout << deadHumans + deadSkeletons << " men and bone-men, gave gave there lives this day";
    }
    else {
        if (humans == 0) {
            cout << "The Skeletons Win!" << endl;
            cout << "They killed all " << deadHumans << " of the humans" << endl;
            cout << "However, at the cost of " << deadSkeletons << " of they're own" << endl;
            cout << "Only " << skeletons << " remain";
        }
        else {
            cout << "The Humans Win!" << endl;
            cout << "They killed all " << deadSkeletons << " of the humans" << endl;
            cout << "However, at the cost of " << deadHumans << " of they're own" << endl;
            cout << "Only " << humans << " remain";
        }
    }
    system("PAUSE");
    return 0;
}
```

oh and I'm sorry about the messy code.

Comment: I think you should learn how to use a debugger.  This would be far more effective and accurate than having the community guess where your code is broken.

Answer (score 1):

Your main 'combat' loop never terminates as nothing in the loop updates 'hHp' or 'sHp'. This means if the 'while' loop starts it never finishes. Also, if neither of the subconditions inside the loop are true the loop doesn't even do anything. I think you need an 'else' case for both subconditions and also setting the hp of both creatures to 0 on death. Something like:

```
    while ((hHp > 0) && (sHp > 0)) {
        if (hAtt >= sHp) {
            skeletons--;
            deadHumans++;
            sHp = 0;
        }
        else
        {
            sHp -= hAtt;
        }
        if (sAtt >= hHp) {
            humans--;
            deadHumans++;
            hHp = 0;
        }
        else
        {
            hHp -= sAtt;
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

This will work for you:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <ctime>
#include <random>

using namespace std;

int main() {
    mt19937 randGen(time(NULL));
    uniform_int_distribution<int> humanatt(4, 8);
    uniform_int_distribution<int> humanhp(50, 100);
    uniform_int_distribution<int> skelatt(4, 8);
    uniform_int_distribution<int> skelhp(50, 100);
    int hAtt, hHp, sAtt, sHp;
    unsigned long humans, skeletons, deadHumans = 0, deadSkeletons = 0;
    cout << "*** Skeletons vs Humans ***" << endl;
    cout << "Input the number of humans: ";
    cin >> humans;
    cout << "Input the number of skeletons: ";
    cin >> skeletons;
    cout << "Beginning combat!!" << endl << endl << "(combat noises)" << endl;

    while (humans > 0 && skeletons > 0) {

        //Define for pair of units (one human, one skeleton)
        hAtt = humanatt(randGen);
        hHp = humanhp(randGen);
        sAtt = skelatt(randGen);
        sHp = skelhp(randGen);

        /*cout << hAtt << endl;
        cout << hHp << endl;
        cout << sAtt << endl;
        cout << sHp << endl;

        system("PAUSE");*/

        //While (somebody in the pair win)
        while (hHp > 0 && sHp > 0) {

            //Human move
            if ((sHp -= hAtt) <= 0) {
                skeletons--;
                deadSkeletons++;

                /*cout << "skeletons: " << skeletons << endl;
                cout << "deadSkeletons: " << deadSkeletons << endl;
                system("PAUSE");*/
            }
            //Skeleton move
            else if ((hHp -= sAtt) <= 0) {
                humans--;
                deadHumans++;

                /*cout << "humans: " << humans << endl;
                cout << "deadHumans: " << deadHumans << endl;
                system("PAUSE");*/
            }
            //One more hits iteration
            /*else {

                cout << "Battle sounds... " << endl;
            }*/
        }

    }

    cout << endl << "Combat has ended!" << endl << endl;
    if ((humans == 0) && (skeletons == 0)) {
        cout << "They all died!" << endl;
        cout << "This was a battle with no winner" << endl;
        cout << deadHumans + deadSkeletons << " men and bone-men, gave gave there lives this day";
    }
    else {
        if (humans == 0) {
            cout << "The Sketeletons Win!" << endl;
            cout << "They killed all " << deadHumans << " of the humans" << endl;
            cout << "However, at the cost of " << deadSkeletons << " of they're own" << endl;
            cout << "Only " << skeletons << " remain";
        }
        else {
            cout << "The Humans Win!" << endl;
            cout << "They killed all " << deadSkeletons << " of the SKELETONS" << endl;
            cout << "However, at the cost of " << deadHumans << " of they're own" << endl;
            cout << "Only " << humans << " remain";
        }
    }
    system("PAUSE");
    return 0;
}
```

Always write what you want to do before coding. Debug your code step by step like in commented regions.
Cheers!